# Getting dates from access to pentaho

Tags: java, pentaho

im new in pentaho, i'm trying to receive data from an access file but i got the actual date and time not the data stored in my access file

i use the microsoft access input and the modified java script value, and when i trie to se my variables in the modified js value i see that the data from the access file is not the same, actually is the real actual date and time

var msg = "The date is .. " +Fecha_Inicio+ "."  then i click on test script

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kDSGLhfbLlXvYVotbkeDmBelc9JjVHrT[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRY7R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you test the script you don't read the data from access. It'll run 10 test rows, and will use a sample value only (which you can modify if you need to test more thoroughly).

It's mostly used to check that there are no syntax errors in your javcascript, for example.

To test the javascript code against the actual Access data, right click the javascript step and choose Preview. That will run the transformation, pause it at 1000 rows and display the data you have at that point.

Comment: thanks nsousa, i was sending my result data to an excel file and there i was cheking my data.